# $h: \mathbb{Z}_{10} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{15}$ an homomorphism such that $h(1)=10$. What is the kernel $K$ of $h$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that the kernel of a group homomorphism $ϕ:G→H$ is defined as
$\kerϕ={g∈G:ϕ(g)=eH}$. That is, $g∈\kerϕ$ϕ if and only if $ϕ(g)=eH$ where $eH$ is the identity of $H$.

Then if $h: \mathbb{Z}_{10} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{15}$ an homomorphism such that $h(1)=10$:

$h(1)=10$

$h(1+1)=10+10=h(2)=5$

$h(2+1)=5+10=h(3)=0$

$h(3+1)=0+10=h(4)=10$

$h(4+1)=10+10=h(5)=5$

$h(5+1)=5+10=h(6)=0$

$h(6+1)=0+10=h(7)=10$

$h(7+1)=10+10=h(8)=5$

$h(8+1)=5+10=h(9)=0$

$h(9+1)=0+10=h(0)=10$

Then the kernel is $\{3,6,9\}$. My question: Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a well-defined map. One way to see this doesn't actually extend to a homomorphism is to note that the kernel of a group homomorphism is a normal subgroup of the whole group. By Lagrange's Theorem, it cannot have order 3, as this does not divide 10.

Alternatively, compute $h(11)$ which should equal $h(1)$, but it doesn't.

Comment: I was just about to make this comment, checking with the First Isomorphism Theorem $\mathbb{Z}_{10} / \ker \phi \simeq \phi(\mathbb{Z}_{10})$ where $|\phi(\mathbb{Z}_{10})| = 3$, yet $|\mathbb{Z}_{10} / \ker \phi|$ is either 1, 2, 5, or 10.

Answer (score 0):

$$h(g) = h(g*1) = g*h(1) = g*10$$

So $g\in\ker(h)$ if $g*10 \equiv 0 \mod 15$. This is true if and only if $g\equiv 0 \mod{3}$. So $g=3,6,9$.

Answer (score 0):

In a homomorphism $h: \mathbb{Z}_{10} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{15}$, the order of $h(1)$ divides $\gcd(10,15)=5$ and so is $1$ or $5$.

But the order of $10$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$ is $3$.

Therefore, there is no homomorphism $h: \mathbb{Z}_{10} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{15}$ with $h(1)=10$.